# Set css for attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table>
    <tr><td test="1">aa</td><td test="2">bb</td><td test="3">cc</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is possible set css, for example background-color:red for attribute test='2'?

I would like use attribute, not add new class or id.

Comment: You should use `data-*` attributes instead of custom ones to avoid problems (and to produce correct HTML), in this case `data-test`.

Comment: @ShonNocolis Why don't you want to use a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("td[test="2"]").css("background-color", "red");
```

Bear in mind though that making up your own attributes will result in invalid HTML.

You could instead use the HTML5 `data-x` to set custom attributes, and filter on that:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr><td data-test="1">aa</td><td data-test="2">bb</td><td data-test="3">cc</td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var $cell = $('TD').filter(function() { 
  return $(this).data("test") == "2";
});
$cell.css("background-color", "red");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8VAuY/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[test=2]").css("background-color", "red");
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/